# AWS EC2 API Throttle for ec2-start-instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Folks,
  We are wondering if there is a throttle limit (increasable) for starting and stopping instances in AWS.  Documentation seems to lack this information.  Is it possible to start/stop 10K instances at approximately same time?

Not readily apparent from the docs. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_ecs

It would probably make sense to queue up such large operations.  Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: You've linked to docs for the wrong service, ECS instead of EC2.  Scroll down, and you should find the link to http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#How_many_instances_can_I_run_in_Amazon_EC2

Answer (score 1):

When you're executing different API commands, you could get "RequestLimitExceeded" error codes. This means that you're calling the APIs too fast.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/errors-overview.html

Describe* (read-only) API methods have higher maximum rates than other (actionable) API methods.

Your application should plan for this error code and when it's seen, wait for a bit then retry your command. Exponential back-off is a good algorithm to use when choosing a pause-time.

If you know that you need to start and/or stop 10k instances, then you could queue them up and process them in a regular and safe rate.